# Handling UILocalNotification fire events

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

So I'm working with UILocalNotification's and I've become quite familiar with how

> didfinishlaunchingwithoptions

and

> didReceiveLocalNotification

are used to handle notifications when they fire. I can fill both those functions with code that does many things.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to get these functions to "interact" with the rest of my App. Let me explain what I mean by that.

Instead of performing the majority of logic inside both of those functions, I initially thought I could create a delegate protocol within my main view controller. The AppDelegate would then register as a delegate and I could then have the notification events call methods within my view controller class and perform most logic there. All of this works just as hoped - except in one case that I did not anticipate.

I've since figured out why it isn't working. I assign the delegate in the viewDidLoad function of my MyViewController:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    appDelegate.delegate = self;
}
```

The problem with doing this is that when the App is cold launched, the didfinishlaunchingwithoptions is called BEFORE the viewDidLoad function of MyViewController. So it never has a chance to become the delegate. There is no chance to handle that first UILocalNotification that I obtain inside didfinishlaunchingwithoptions with my delegate protocol methods.

So I know what my problem is, I just can't think of a better way to go about handling these UILocalNotification events. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution, probably this will not be a good one.

You can rely on [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Implement your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   //other code
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"notificationReceived"];
   return YES;
}
```

And in the `viewDidLoad` of `MyViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"notificationReceived"])
   {
      //notification received do the stuff
      //reset the bool
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"notificationReceived"];
   }
 }
```

Comment: @dtmland: Thanks for your comment. All the best.